# Passing parameters from JSP page to a java method to persist to a database

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jpa

I am trying to create a registration JSP page which when submit is clicked I would like it to pass the information entered to an addUser method in a java class

This is my JSP Page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
            <h2>Signup Details</h2>
            <form action="RegisterUser.java" method="post">
            <br/>Username:<input type="text" name="username">
            <br/>Password:<input type="password" name="password">
            <br/>Email:<input type="text" name="email">

            <%= String name = request.getParameter("username");
                String pass = request.getParameter("password");
                String email = request.getParameter("email");
                User u = new User();
                u.setName(name);
                u.setPassword(pass);
                u.setEmail(email);%>

            <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit" action="RegisterUser.addUser(u)">
            </form>
        </center>

</body>
</html>
```

When Submit is clicked I want to add the details to a database using the following method

```
public class RegisterUser {
     private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "User";
     private static EntityManagerFactory factory;
     private User user;

     public void addUser(User user){
         factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
         EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
         // Create new user
         em.getTransaction().begin();
         em.persist(user);
         em.getTransaction().commit();
         em.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a Servlet that processes your form and calls the addUser() method.

You can't invoke a Java method directly from JavaScript.

Here's a good tutorial on the subject.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-form-data.htm

Answer (score 1):

You generally pass request data to `Servlet` which acts as controller and depending on request it delegates logical calls to services class

Check out the complete flow with example and nice explanation on [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) wiki page

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with a Servlet that will work as `Controller` in your `Model`. The `View`, the JSP in your case, should be able to communicate with your Model using a Servlet.

For a good separation between the Model, Controller and the View you can use Spring MVC. Here is a good example that you can follow as start point: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try closing down eclipse and opening it again? If not try restarting eclipse. It works for me every time.

Comment: Thanks very much Niall it Worked! I can't believe it was so simple in the end.

Comment: No problem. I am very knowledgeable with the computers thing and I'm happy to share my gift with others.